# How to generate beat for rhythm game from midi file

Tags: qt, midi, qml, meego

I want to make a rhythm game which pre-generate beat from a midi file.
but I don't really understand about the data structure of midi file and how to generate those beat.
how should I accomplished this?

for your info I'm using Qt for Meego.
and there's also one problem I found, QML Element Audio for meego cannot play .mid file. I dont how to solve it. any solution>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'r looking for is "Music Sequencer Design"

Take a look at [this document](http://www.gamasutra.com/gdcarchive/2001/patterson.doc) from [gamasutra.com](http://www.gamasutra.com/gdcarchive/2001/)

Comment: any real example of how to implement these ? I can't really understand it :(

Comment: Check this out (there are lot of projects with source code available in different lang -pick based on ur lang)  https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=midi&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories